# Is it possible to encode very large video in Media Foundation (larger than 4K)

Tags: video-encoding, ms-media-foundation

It seems that the max resolution for the built in H264 MFT is 4096 × 2304 pixels according to the documentation. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd797815(v=vs.85).aspx

Is it possible to use a different MFT that would allow larger formats or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limitations are with respect to the encoded format, and the transforms, and not with Media Foundation itself.  It seems [H265 (HEVC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Video_Coding) can support up to [4320p (7680 x 4320)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4320p) with improved picture quality over H264.  However, as you probably noticed, H265 is supported on Windows 10, but their current implementation of the [H265 decoder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt218785(v=vs.85).aspx) also has a limitation of 4096 x 2304.  It may be possible to purchase H265 SDKs which contain transforms and sinks for other versions of windows, and support higher resolutions.

8K UHD [4320p] info described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra-high-definition_television).

And info on the names of given resolutions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_display_resolution).

[Google's VP9](http://www.webmproject.org/hardware/vp9/) project only supports up to 4096 x 2304.
Some have noticed and wrote about Google engineers working on VP10, and have started pushing code into the [public libvpx repository](https://chromium.googlesource.com/webm/libvpx) where VP8 and VP9 reside.  But that will be a while, and much will change before it is ready.

Of course, if you are feeling a bit code crazy, you could always write custom transform and sink for Media Foundation, and support whatever you like with respect to format and resolution, perhaps [QUHD 16K (15360 x 8640)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_display_resolution#QUHD_16K_.2815360x8640.29).

Sounds like you have an interesting project on your hands, but you may be a bit ahead of your time.
Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

You make a good point (with your comment).  If your color format is standard, there is a chance you can use [CLSID_CColorConvertDMO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819079(v=vs.85).aspx) to perform the conversion, which will use SIMD registers/instructions when possible (not sure if there are size constraints).  It has a dual interface as a DMO and an MFT.  It definitely makes life a bit easier.

After creating the CLSID_CColorConvertDMO instance, and setting the input and output types (format, frame size, etc), create an [IMFSample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms702192(v=vs.85).aspx) (using MFCreateSample), and an [IMFMediaBuffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms696261(v=vs.85).aspx) (using [MFCreateMemoryBuffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695212(v=vs.85).aspx)) to the sample (using [IMFSample::AddBuffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms697465(v=vs.85).aspx)), then all that is necessary is to call [ProcessInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms703131(v=vs.85).aspx) and [ProcessOutput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms704014(v=vs.85).aspx) to convert the buffer (create all items upfront).

RomanR also provides some code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341038/imftransform-interface-of-color-converter-dsp-giving-e-invalidarg-on-setinputtyp).

If your format is not standard, you still have good options.  After using C++ AMP for a bit (which is a wrapper for DirectCompute and HLSL), it felt more natural for me to simply use DirectCompute and HLSL directly.  In the simplest terms, you create views of the data which map to the GPU from your memory stucts, and HLSL is very C like, and not hard to learn.

After your transforms are taken care of, you only have to decide the storage format (headers, etc), and provide the source and sink (for reading and writing/displaying).  I suspect it would be a bit bloated compared to H264/H265 (increased I/O) but there would be little overhead with the conversion.

Comment: That's very interesting and helpful. If I got that correctly, you are saying that H.264 in general, regardless of the encoder has a resolution limit?
The same thing applies to H.265 and VP9. 
I was thinking on hacking a custom transform. However I was hoping to have hardware support at least on the decoding end. If my stream will be non standard, that will not happen.

Comment: @cloudraven - editing answer instead of long comment.

Comment: I don't think Color Converter DMO is hardware accelerated, but it's decently optimized using SIMD (many directions at least) and is pretty powerful, and on par compared with other well known scaling options.

Comment: @RomanR. - Thanks for the note, I will make the correction.  In the cases I have used it, SIMD must have been employed, since my CPU utilization dropped to almost nothing, in which case, I was quite happy.

Comment: Jeff, Roman. Thanks for sharing all this wisdom. I wasn't aware of CColorConvertDMO. ColorConverting in SIMD will be very useful, if not for this, for other things I am doing. 
I learned quite a bit today. Thanks